# Was buddha aware of future or future way of living?

Tags: doubt

I need a suggestion. I raised up as an aspirant on my side. As per my family (attached people) i was a sign of glory to them. In India, i did completed my education with good grades. I started my career on a positive note. 3 years back i was earning 1 lakhs plus every three months. Then i joined psychedelics and also started learning about religion/science related people and their thoughts. I came along buddhism. I managed to buy our own home. Now i am earning less than 1 lakhs a year. My family's financial earning was always like hand to mouth, same is mine now a days. This situation is so bad to us. To me its like i am all negative right now. I want to know 'what is the right way of earning life, when i don't want to hurt anyone else including me 'as i don't like any corporate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Change in circumstances

This is a fact of life. You have your ups and downs. Worrying or resentment towards the situation will not change it. You have to accept it with grace and then do what is wihtin your control to improve your situation.

- Use of psychedelics

This interferes with your mindfulness. So best is to sop using them. If it is difficult perhaps you can use professional help. This might also help in solving your changed circumstances.

- Right way to earn a living

The right way to earn a living is a way which does not harm yourself or others and have a moral basis. Avoid ways to earn a living without lies, deceit, killing, debauchery, etc.

Comment: Sir, i am in sales & marketing. May be you won't believe it but it is all about a thief act in all ways, here now a days. People know that they are selling slow toxic but they try sell it like anything. I am sorry to be a part of it from last 5 years. But now its getting worse. For a fair today 'we are killing our chances to be a tomorrow'. Its getting almost insane as sales-rush is growing. Over all i blame corporations for all this insanity. What i should do ,so that i can earn fair enough to give to my family ?

Comment: I am in pharmaceuticals sales.

Comment: @jitin Look at it with the right motivation. People do need meditation. Approach your job as a service to humanity than pill pushing.

Comment: Sir, my email id is jitinkhanna16@gmail.com. I'd appreciate it you will counsel me regarding the same (i am afraid of contacting psycho doctors).

Comment: They just want to fullfil the commitements they had made with mnc's & local medicine companies.

Comment: When i do not do pill-push kinda working then i lose my job/earning/health of my family. in past 5 years i have changed 6 mnc's.

Comment: my email is sirinath1978m at gmail dot com. I am not sure if I can counsel you.

Comment: Sir, i am feeling like an animal chained on my neck with their obligations to see myself as a LIVING being. But i feel dead.

Comment: Okay, then thank you. I don't know why you do not have enough positive confidence to counsel me, when i am ready to speak the truth of me in whole to you!

Comment: Why don't you try a couple of courses at: http://dhamma.org/. This might help calming your anguish but will not solve it. When you have a clearer mind then you can approach your problem systematically.

Comment: Send me a email with your problem. I am not a professional through.